# Why is change detection not working in my Angular 2 code?

Tags: angular

What am I doing wrong here. I have created a service that has one property that I am updating with `setInterval`.

I am injecting this service into a component and want the component to watch the property for changes to update the screen. But only the initial value for `numCount` is shown and it is never updated.

Example:

Here is a test service I created

```ts
export class TestService {
    numCount: number;

    constructor() {
      this.numCount = 0;

      var self = this;
      setInterval(function() {
          self.numCount++;
          console.log('from service', self.numCount);
      }, 500);
    }
}
```

Here is the component

```ts
export class MyComponentView implements OnChanges  {

    displayString: string;

    constructor(testService: TestService) {

          this.displayString = testService.numCount.toString();
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes) {
      console.log(changes); // nothing logs out, even though the testService.numCount is being incremented in the class. 
    }
}
```

If you see here, `testService.numCount` is being increased by one every half second. But when I display it on screen through the component, it does not update. How can I watch the data from the injected service so it updates on screen?

I am displaying the `displayString` on the screen and the number does not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just copy the value once and your component only works with this one value.

```ts
this.displayString = testService.numCount.toString();
```

You can alternatively bind your view to the service directly

```ts
{{testService.numCount}}
```

or add an `EventEmitter` to your service

```ts
export class TestService {
    numCount: number;

    numCountChange = new EventEmitter();
    constructor() {
      this.numCount = 0;

      var self = this;
      setInterval(function() {
          self.numCount++;
          self.numCountChange.next(self.numCount);
          console.log('from service', self.numCount);
      }, 500);
    }
}
```

and then in you component subscribe to the changes

```ts
constructor(testService: TestService) {
   testService.numCountChange.subscribe(value => {
       this.displayString = testService.numCount.toString();
   });
}
```

`ngOnChanges()` is also only called when an `@Input() xxx` is changed from a binding like `<my-comp [xxx]="parentProperty">` not when a normal field changes in your component.

Comment: how could I set it up so a have a function re-run everytime testService.numCount changes? Like $scope.watch

Comment: I see you are using EventEmitter. This is a way that could work. But what about alternative? In Angular 1, I could just use scope.watch. Simple. Why is there no equivalent? Also how do I bind the service to the view? testService.numCount is not available. It seems like I need to inject the service into the constructor and assign it to a class property. Please clarify this. Thanks!

Comment: `EventEmitter` or `Observables` are push instead of pull (`$scope.watch`) which is much more efficient. Performance has a very high priority with Angular2. I guess you need to copy the injected service to a local variable in the constructor. `this.testService = testService;` then it should work.

Comment: @nearpoint, instead of `this.testService = testService;` you can use this [TypeScript shorthand](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#classes-privatepublic-modifiers) (see section Parameter properties):  `constructor(private testService: TestService) {...}`

Comment: Thanks @MarkRajcok ! I have seen it but wasn't too show about when and how exactly it works.

Comment: ngOnChanges() is also only called when an @Input() xxx is changed from a binding like <my-comp [xxx]="parentProperty"> not when a normal field changes in your component.   this is very helpful.